# how to remove/delete bot userpic in telegram

Tags: image, api, settings, telegram, telegram-bot

I can add bot userpic using /setuserpic command.
I need to know how to remove it.
Tried to delete bot userpicture via BotFather, but /empty command not working.

Comment: Currently there seems to be no way to remove the pic completely. But why?

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is not possible to just remove a photo from telegram bot, You can set a new picture by sending `/setuserpic` command then select your bot and send new profile picture; this replaces the old profile with a new picture.

You can replace your old profile picture with a white blank picture [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8IDq.jpg)